# Why i cannot update value of specific index in an array in react js via set State?

Tags: reactjs

I have an array like below

```
[
    1:false,  
    9:false,
    15:false,
    19:false,
    20:true,
    21:true
]
```

[image]
on click i have to change the value of specific index in an array.
To update value code is below.

```
OpenDropDown(num){
    var tempToggle;
    if ( this.state.isOpen[num] === false) {
      tempToggle = true;
    } else {
      tempToggle = false;
    }
    const isOpenTemp = {...this.state.isOpen};
    isOpenTemp[num] = tempToggle;
    this.setState({isOpen:isOpenTemp}, function(){
        console.log(this.state.isOpen);
    });
}
```

but when i console an array it still shows old value, i have tried many cases but unable to debug.

Comment: Does your array not have a zero index?

Comment: your data is `Array` or `Object`? the data above doesn't look like an array or object neither.

Comment: @YasserHussain no it doesn't have zero index

Comment: I think the empty object in array cause issue.

Comment: but i need this as it is, any suggestion?

Comment: Does `num` have correct value? @HassanShafique

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your array has several `empty` value. And functions like `map`, `forEach` will not loop through these items, then the index will not right. 
You should format the `isOpen` before setState. Remove the empty value

```
const formattedIsOpen = this.state.isOpen.filter(e => e)
this.setState({isOpen: formattedIsOpen})
```

Or use [Spread_syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) if you want to render all the empty item

```
[...this.state.isOpen].map(e => <div>{Your code here}</div>)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working solution,

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Stack extends Component {
  state = {
    arr: [
      { id: "1", value: false },
      { id: "2", value: false },
      { id: "9", value: false },
      { id: "20", value: true },
      { id: "21", value: true }
    ]
  };
  OpenDropDown = event => {
    let num = event.target.value;
    const isOpenTemp = [...this.state.arr];
    isOpenTemp.map(item => {
      if (item.id === num) item.value = !item.value;
    });
    console.log(isOpenTemp);
    this.setState({ arr: isOpenTemp });
  };

  render() {
    let arr = this.state.arr;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <select onChange={this.OpenDropDown}>
          {arr.map(item => (
            <option value={item.id}>{item.id}</option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Stack;
```

i hope it helps!